# Flask + ngrok - Access to subdomain.ngrok.io was denied - 403 Error

Tags: flask, ngrok

I was starting a simple Flask app and successfully hosted it locally at port 5000.

However, I couldn't set up a tunnel to a public url via ngrok.

Here are my codes:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "<p>Hello, World!!</p>"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My local host is showing "Hello World!!" normally but clicking on the ngrok page shows this:

[image: Successfully loaded ngrok]

[image: But cannot access through the subdomain url]

Answer (score 30):

There is an issue where the latest mac os mojave uses the default port for flask. To resolve it, head over to System Preferences > Sharing and unselect the AirPlay Receiver. Or change your default flask port to something other than 5000 using flask run --port=5002 and restart your ngrok server: ngrok http 5002

Comment: Great answer. Recently started using Ngrok and was stuck on this for almost a day. This worked for me.

Comment: Also worked for me!

Comment: Thank you so much. Was running through the OKTA SCIM2 + Flask tutorial and ran into this. This fixed it up perfectly. :)

Comment: Worked for me as well and I am on macOS Monterey

Comment: Same here, the suggested solution worked for me as well! Thanks!

Comment: THANK YOU this was bugging me forever! I don't understand this at all though...how is it related to AirPlay Receiver?

Comment: awesome, thank you so much for the suggestion to disable AirPlay Receiver

Answer (score 4):

You can simply change the port by passing port argument to run:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5002)
```